# JS Callback is not working

Tags: javascript, callback

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
   <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">      
    function f() {    
       g(function(err){
         if(!err){
            alert('Call me later');
         }
       });
    }    
    function g(callback) {
        setTimeout(function(){ alert("Call me first after 3 sec"); }, 3000);
        callback(false);            
    }
  </SCRIPT>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY onload="f()">
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

In the above code snippet my objective is to understand the JavaScript callback feature.

I put two alerts in. I had wanted 'Call me first' to alert after 3 sec and *then* 'Call me later'. However, this is not the order the the alerts occur.

Comment: Check your console. I wouldn't imagine any of that would work given the leading `<!--`

Comment: @FissureKing — Browsers ignore HTML comments at the edge of script elements. They are allowed there so that browsers which don't support JavaScript (i.e. which are of a Netscape 1.0 vintage) won't render the script as text in the page).

Comment: @Arijit Chowdhury — You are writing HTML 3.2 and putting defences in your code against lack of support for JavaScript in Netscape 1.0. You really should find a resource that has been updated at some point in the 21st century to learn from. [MDN is a good choice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web).

Comment: @Quentin Interesting. I've been writing JS for a long time but not quite that long :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the asynchronous call you made.

Calling the function `g` will take two actions for its two lines of code. First, it will create a task and schedule it to run in 3000 milliseconds. Second, it will call the callback. The callback then alerts `'Call me later'`.

If the code in the timeout had called the callback, then call me later would have come second, but since it did not, and the timeout is not a blocking call, you see the current behavior.

If you wanted the alert to come second, the timeout should make the call.

```
function g(callback) {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
       alert("Call me first after 3 sec"); 
       callback(false);
    }, 3000);            
}
```

Comment: Can you quickly change and let me know how to achieve

Answer (score -4):

Script tag has no such attribute as 'language'.

Instead of

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
```

try

```
<script type="javaccript">
```

Comment: It did in HTML 3.2. That was replaced with the type attribute in HTML 4 (but `javaccript` (or `javascript` for that matter) is not a valid type, so it will cause browsers to ignore the script entirely). HTML 5 expects you not to use a language **or** type attribute for JavaScript. (That said, adding `language=javascript` does no *harm*, it is just bloat).

Comment: these are same .